# Why can an object access attributes of a sibling class?

Tags: python, class, properties, siblings

In below, with Bird and Worm derived from Animal, why can a Worm object be able to access an attribute in Bird class? But then not access a method in Bird class? I don't want Worm to be able to access Bird at all.

```
class Animal:
    name = None
class Bird(Animal):
    color = None
    def print_bird(self): print(f"bird color = {self.color}")
class Worm(Animal):
    length = None
    def print_worm(self): print(f"worm length = {self.length}")
W1 = Worm()
W1.length = 10 # works as expected
W1.print_worm() # works as expected
W1.color = "brown" # ??? Bird.color should only be for birds
W1.print_bird() # as expected, AttributeError: 'Worm' object has no attribute 'print_bird'
```

Comment: Because python has dynamic attributes. You aren't accessing the attributes of the sibling class, you're just creating a new attribute `color` on your instance of `Worm`

Comment: You aren't. You are just assigning attributes on instances, not on the class

Comment: Attributes can be accessed and assigned anywhere, unless the class takes special measures to prevent it.

Comment: As @Cfreak mentioned, you are creating a new attribute for that particular `Worm` instance. You could have also written `W1.blahblah = "hello world"`, and that would have worked just as easily.

Comment: Thank you. I can now pass this explanation on to others.